# jQuery: How to disable checkboxes only

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, disable

I am using the code below which I found on a website and it works perfectly.

I have a 25 question-quiz made up of radio buttons and checkboxes.

If on the same page I have both radio buttons as well as checkboxes, something goes wrong. The code below counts both of these, but I only want it to count the ticked off checkboxes.

- Currently once I hit the max answers, I cannot answer the remaining radio button questions; or vice versa, radio buttons before the checkboxes count towards the max number of answers.
- The code also disables both radio buttons and checkboxes, so I'd like to find a way to make it to disable the checkboxes only.

I could split the code into even more divs, but that is going to become very complicated as my jQuery controls the flow of the quiz using divs:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question").length > 0) {
      disableInputs($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question")[0]);        
    }
  });
});

function disableInputs(questionElement) {
  console.log(questionElement);
  if ($(questionElement).data('max-answers') == undefined) {
    return true;
  } else {
    maxAnswers = parseInt($(questionElement).data('max-answers'), 10); 
    if ($(questionElement).find(":checked").length >= maxAnswers) {
      $(questionElement).find(":not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $(questionElement).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the main quiz:

```html
<div class="Q8 question" data-max-answers="3">
  <h2>Access Control Questions</h2><br>

  <strong>Is it ok to share the door access code?</strong><br>
  <input type="radio" id="ac1" name="access1" value="0">Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" id="ac2" name="access1" value="1">No<br><br>
  <br><strong><label for="access1">From the list below select those that are the aims of an Access Control System (Maximum of 3) </strong></span></label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ac3" name="access"  value="1" /> To ensure only authorised users have access to our systems</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ac4" name="access"  value="1" /> To protect physical access to our offices</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ac4a" name="access" value="0" /> To give you access to other users passwords</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ac5" name="access"  value="1" /> To ensure users have access to systems they require access too</p>

  <br><strong>A client is visiting and asks to use your computer, what should you do?</strong><br>
  <input type="radio" id="ac6" name="access5" value="0">Let them use your computer because they are a client so can do what they wish<br>
  <input type="radio" id="ac7" name="access5" value="1">Politely say you are not allowed to do that and refer them to the manager they have come to visit<br>
  <input type="radio" id="ac8" name="access5" value="0">Pretend to be on a call and hope they go away<br><br>
</div>

<div class="Q8a">
  <input id="Q8PrevBut" type="button" Value="Back"> 
  <input id="Q8NextBut" type="button" Value="Next"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `:not(:checked)` returns both radio buttons and checkboxes. You could try to make the selector more specific by adding `input[type=checkbox]`, see below:

```js
if ($(questionElement).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= maxAnswers)
```

...and do the same when disabling checkboxes:

```js
$(questionElement).find("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Awesome! Would you be so kind to mark the answer as accepted? Future visitors might benefit from it